# Why do some of my games say they are expired even though I renewed my PS+ membership?

Tags: playstation-plus

My PS plus membership renewed in May.  Today when I went to play the games I got using it, they said they were expired but some were still playable.  Games playable: Soul Caliber list swords, and Infamous 2. Games not playable: Demon's Soul,  Kingdoms of Amalur,  and Grid 2.   Do I just need to redownload them to be able to play again?  If I redownload them,  will my saves stay on my PS3?

Update,    I just tried redownloading grid 2 and now all are working again

Answer (score 1):

No, you shouldn't need to re-download all of them as you discovered. You only have to force the system to refresh it's licenses. When you download any of the free PSN+ content, it automatically stamps that content with an expiration date that is the same as your subscription expiration at that moment. When you extend your subscription, it doesn't update all of your downloads immediately.

But, if for some reason you do re-download a title (even if it's one you've previously deleted). All of your game save data should still be present on your PS3 as save files are stored independent of your content licenses and software downloads.

Oh and one other note. If for some reason you let your PSN+ membership laps, you could permanently loose some of your previously downloaded free games. I have seen that there are a number of titles that remain free contingent on a continuous membership.